# Why is throwing one part of the EPR state away not the same as measuring it and not looking at the result?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-measurements

Disclaimer: The amount of sense that the following makes might differ depending on which interpretation of quantum mechanics you are supporting.

Suppose that I have the EPR-state
\begin{align*}
 \frac{\mid 0 0 \rangle +  \mid 1 1 \rangle }{ \sqrt{2}} 
\end{align*}
If I throw the second system out (i.e. taking the partial trace over the second system) I end up with the pure state.  "EDIT: This is not the correct way to throw the second system out"
\begin{align*}
 \frac{\vert 0 \rangle +  \vert 1 \rangle }{ \sqrt{2}} 
\end{align*}
If I measure the second system, but I do not look at the measurement then I end up then the system is described by the density matrix
\begin{align*}
\frac{\vert 0 \rangle \langle 0 \vert + \vert 1 \rangle \langle 1 \vert }{2} 
\end{align*}
These systems are fundamentally different. Do you have an intuition/explanation why I do not get effectively the same system?

Comment: How do you define the partial trace of a ket, i.e. how do you obtain your second equation?

Comment: Isn't taking partial trace the way you generally get a _mixed_ state?

Comment: Thanks, of course this makes no sense!

Answer (score 2):

As was pointed out in the comments by Jakob and Rusian. The point/mistake is that you can't (of course) just throw away the second part of the kets to throw away the second system. You need to take the partial trace of the corresponding $density$ $ matrix$. Then you will end up with the same as the density matrix when you measure and never look at the measurement.